# Google Cloud text recognition REST endpoint?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I can access Googles vision API using a REST endpoint like so: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth

Is there an equivalent to send post requests to the text analytics? As far as I can see there is no simple endpoint which takes an api key for authentication?

Comment: Do you mean the Natural Language API (https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text analysis, using the [Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/), you may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/) as a reference for REST endpoints. Each endpoints in that reference expands into more details containing information such as the HTTP methods accepted, the response body and the request body.